# cannot store list of objects as one of the parameters of a parent object in cassandra using Kundera

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, spring-data-cassandra, kundera

I have a list of objects that i store in cassandra,

```
[
  {
     deviceId: [xxxx],
     status: On, 
     metric: Metric(Watts=10,Current=10),
     resources: Resources(cpu=u'2', memory=u'512Mi'),
     deviceName: ['test'],
     deviceUsageParams : "Not able to save this param since it is a list of UDT (object)"
  }
]
```

The parent object is

```
Public static class Device{
 private int deviceId,
 private boolean status,
 private Metric metric,
 private Resources resources,
 private string deviceName,
 Private List<DeviceUsageParameter> deviceUsageParams
}
```

I have another attribute deviceUsageParams that is another list of UDT object,

I am trying to store a list of Device object into cassandra, using Kundera wrapper, but it does not allow me to store the List if UDT (i.e list of DeviceUsageParameter)

Is it possible to store a list objects as one of the attribute of another object in a list using kundera wrapper for cassandra?

TIA..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It is possible to store list of custom objects in Cassandra using Kundera.

You should add `@ElementCollection` annotation on that field, if you did not already.

Check this [test case](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/blob/trunk/src/kundera-cassandra/cassandra-core/src/test/java/com/impetus/client/cassandra/udt/UdtAsEmbeddablesCRUDTest.java) and [object](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/blob/trunk/src/kundera-cassandra/cassandra-core/src/test/java/com/impetus/client/cassandra/udt/PersonUDT.java#L71) for reference.

HTH!